# Is there a Markdown editor for iOS?

Tags: text-editor, ios, markdown

I was quite impressed with Mou for OS X from [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25/markdown-editor-for-osx-that-includes-a-preview-ideally-in-real-time/30#30), and now I'd like to get something like it for my iOS devices.

Must:

- Use the Stack Exchange 'style' of markdown
- Run natively, no webapps please
- Have a preview

Nice to have:

- A *live* preview
- Universal app, working on both iPhone and iPad.

Is there an app that meets my needs? I've seen [Elements](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/elements/), but it doesn't seem to have a live preview from what I can tell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### An app that comes to mind is [Byword](http://bywordapp.com/).

From what I can see, it does use the Stack Exchange 'style' of markdown, runs natively, and features preview integration. I'm not sure if the preview is "live" but it will allow you to see / review your markdown before exporting / saving it. It is definitely universal (works on iPhone & iPad) and will even sync to your Mac if you're running it on there too.

Last but not least, it also features other things such as a dark theme (for late-night writing) & an offline mode if that's of any interest to you.

[image: application screen]

[image: application running on devices]

Answer (score 2):

How about [Trunk Notes](http://www.trunknotes.com/) by "Apps On The Move"? 
I'm not sure if it uses the Stack Exchange 'style' of markdown, but it definitely uses Markdown syntax

Comment: _Sorry I didn't realize this question was asked so long ago_

Comment: nothing to apologize, late answers are not bad by itself...! ;-)

Comment: The link is not valid anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately Trunk Notes has been discontinued. There is another editor that can work in Markdown called "1Writer", although I'm not sure about links. I mainly use it as in text mode - as a text editor.