# Markdown editor for Windows with live rendering in the editing pane, NOT in a separate preview pane

Tags: windows, text-editor, markdown

There are lots of Markdown editors out there but I couldn't find one in which the viewer was built into the editing pane itself.

An example of what I *don't* want is these SE sites, where the question/answer Markdown preview appears down below. Similarly, the vast majority of existing Markdown editors have two separate side-by-side panes, one for editing and the other for the live preview. This is *not* what I want.

What I want is for the Markdown rendering to occur **right where you're typing**, replacing the typed text with marked-down text as you go along.

Is there anything like this? I'm on Windows but a webapp (or even just raw JS/HTML) would be cool too.

Comment: See also: [Markdown editor for OSX that includes a preview, ideally in real time?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25)

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the answers miss the point. The preview is not supposed to be in a separate pane as the input.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought about using Markdown only for serialization and editing it  with a WYSIWYG program.

Answer (score 32):

*Last update: 2023-05-06*

Having a similar need to the OP, I searched the whole web for current solutions. There's no current perfect solution, but there are a few ones that might be worth a try.

Note that I had additional requirements to realtime/inline previewing, such as: multidocuments tabbing, table of contents for quick navigation, lightweight, markup hiding/showing (sourcecode mode) with styling kept and finally autosave of documents and of session.

I will here describe two categories of editors that can fit OP's purpose depending on what exact kind of previewing is expected (**inline preview** vs **inline styling**). I will describe a few main features non exhaustively, you should consult the websites to get more information. I also chose to leave split-pane only editors (ie, without inline preview nor styling) out of the picture, as there are plenty and are explicitly excluded by OP.

Note that I have personally tested all the ones running on Windows.

---

## Inline preview (aka realtime preview or [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG))

All the following editors allow you to type Markdown markup, and automagically display the resulting style instantly inside the editor (no split-pane for preview).

This is also sometimes called WYSIWYG, but this is different here as you do not necessarily have to use the toolbars to format the text: with inline preview you can just input markup code and it will display the result dynamically. In some sense, this is very similar to what [LyX](https://www.lyx.org) pioneered for LaTeX.

There are basically two types of inline preview: per block (refresh the styling after you leave a block, eg, by going to the next line/block) or per character (ie, as you type).

I am not demonstrating image insertion but they can almost all preview images, both local and remote.

Note that almost none of the app here supports multi-document tabs (yet?), except for the note-taking oriented apps.

### [MarkText](https://marktext.app/)

[image: MarkText]

```
Opensource
Cross-platform (Windows + MacOSX + Linux)
Inline preview
Mouse-friendly interface (easy to insert a markdown construct from menus, or by click at the beginning of the line, or by highlighting a text, options are then displayed)
Math support (LaTeX)
Sourcecode mode
Support for a lot of markdown constructs: tasks, code blocks, HTML block, 
Export to HTML, PDF
Focus and typewriter modes
Table of content
Integrated search
Multi-tabs, multi-documents
Support for images, but not for embedded videos
Support for complex constructs, such as graphs, such as vega-lite, or mermaid
Basic autosave support (check File > Autosave). Currently working on a full session manager with more advanced autosave.
Basic support for attachments (either in a folder defined by user, or transparently uploaded to an online repository)
```

Note: this project is in [very active development](https://github.com/marktext/marktext) and already has a big community. It is a personal favorite, it managed to catch up with older editors in terms of features (or even surpass them).

### [Zettlr](https://www.zettlr.com/)

[image: Zettlr]

```
Opensource
Cross-platform (Windows + MacOSX + Linux)
Inline preview (but mixing both rendered and some unrendered but dimmed down markdown formatting, eg, bold and italics)
No sourcecode mode (but there is a readability mode to highlight non-markup text content)
Full note manager, multi-tabs
Attachments support
Bibliography and citation support
Footnotes support
Tables support
Tasks support
Table of content
Mathematical equation support (LaTeX)
Lots of importing and exporting formats: HTML, PDF, DOCX, LaTeX (great for scientific collaborations!)
Code blocks with syntax highlighting
Search (and replace) function integrated
Statistics graphs
Autosave (any change is saved)
Notebook paradigm: you select a folder, and all your notes will be stored inside. It is thus easy to have multiple notebooks and switch between them.
Tags
Fully localized in lots of languages
```

Note: this software was initially made for scientists, hence the extensive support for attachments, bibliography and footnotes. The extensive import/export from/to LaTeX and DOCX is a killer feature for researchers which can ease collaborations. In the end, we could say it's the Markdown equivalent of Zim Desktop Wiki, they are very similar in their philosophy and feature set.

### [Texts](http://www.texts.io/)

[image: Texts.io]

```
Commercial (but cheap: 19$)
Win + MacOSX
Inline preview + Presentation support too + Bibliography support + Footnotes
Math support
Can import LaTeX documents
No sourcecode mode (cannot show Markdown)
No autosave nor tabs.
No task list support.
```

### [Abricotine](http://abricotine.brrd.fr/)

[image: Abricotine]

```
Opensource (GPL)
Win + Mac + Linux
Inline preview + TOC navigation (Table of Content)
Math support
Only sourcecode mode (cannot hide markup, links cannot be beautified)
Actively in development (so the following issues may resolve fast)
Bug with loading external pictures under https
Cannot click on links
No [autosave](https://github.com/brrd/Abricotine/issues/17) nor [tabs](https://github.com/brrd/Abricotine/issues/10) (but issues are open, feel free to +1 or even contribute a patch if you know [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)!)
```

### [Typora](https://www.typora.io/)

[image: Typora]

[Original announcement](http://abnerlee.github.io/typora/2015/03/11/why-typora/)

```
Commercial, free during beta
Win + Mac (+ Linux in the future)
Inline preview + TOC navigation (called Outline)
Math support
Both sourcecode and no markup mode are available.
Autosave + documents recovery
Can insert an auto-updating TOC (in addition to TOC navigation)
No bibliography support (yet?) but can add "link reference" and footnotes.
Auto-reload notification when document changes.
Live preview as-you-type of mathematical equations.
No multi-documents tabs.
```

### [Qute](http://www.inkcode.net/qute)

[image: Qute]

```
Opensource
Win + Mac + Linux
Zenware
Inline preview
Math support
No task list support
```

### [FoldingText](http://www.foldingtext.com/)

[image: FoldingText]

```
Commercial (free limited version available)
Mac
Inline preview (sourcecode mode only, cannot hide markup)
Automatic cumulative time computation from task description
```

### [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/)

[image: TagSpaces]

```
OpenSource (AGPL v3)
Cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, Firefox, Chrome)
Inline preview
Documents manager
Tags
```

Note: this is a very interesting solution if you do not just want to write notes but also manage files.

### Web-based apps with inline preview

- [Lexical by FaceBook](https://github.com/facebook/lexical), a very extensible framework for rich-text editors that supports Markdown syntax and can export/render to Markdown on-the-fly via a native plugin, although internally it uses its own markup. It can be easily extended in terms of functionalities or to support more languages.
- [ProseMirror Markdown WYSIWYG editor](https://prosemirror.net/)
- [laobubu/HyperMD: A WYSIWYG Markdown Editor for browsers. Break the Wall between writing and previewing.](https://github.com/laobubu/HyperMD)
- [Hallo.js - Editing Markdown in WYSIWYG](http://hallojs.org/demo/markdown/)
- [pell - jaredreich.com](https://jaredreich.com/pell/)
- [Alex-D/Trumbowyg: A lightweight and amazing WYSIWYG JavaScript editor - 20kB only (8kB gzip)](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg)
- [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/) with [ep_markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_markdown) and [ep_markdownify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_markdownify) plugins (plus it allows for collaborative edition, [lots of other plugins here](https://static.etherpad.org/plugins.html))
- [Marklight Editor](http://marklighteditor.com/)
- [Pen](https://github.com/sofish/pen#readme)
- [Medium editor](https://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/) with the [Medium Editor Markdown extension](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/medium-editor-markdown)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with [Markdown plugin](http://hectorguo.com/CKEditor-Markdown-Plugin/) - but note the plugin only supports a limited subset of Markdown markup.
- [md-wysiwyg](http://md-wysiwyg.sourceforge.net/) (in Python!)
- [Simditor](http://simditor.tower.im/) with [Markdown extension](https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor-markdown) (or [this one](https://github.com/huyinghuan/simditor-marked)).
- [DIY tutorial using contentEditable property of div and MutationObserver](http://pothibo.com/2015/3/building-a-markdown-editor) ([mirror here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616192810/http://pothibo.com/2015/3/building-a-markdown-editor))

### [Marko editor](http://marko-editor.com)

[image: Marko editor]

```
Opensource (not released yet)
Win + Mac + Linux
Inline preview of Markdown + WYSIWYG
```

### [Vis-a-Wiki](http://marko-editor.com/vis-a-wiki/)

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwiKrhyfAUY)
[image: Vis-a-Wiki]

```
Opensource (not released yet)
Win + Mac + Linux
Inline preview of Markdown
Note-taking oriented (multi-documents)
Same author as Marko Editor (and same codebase)
Mix between a note taking app and a mind-mapping software, with automatic graph reorganization algorithms
Everything is stored as plain text
```

*Personal note: this app seems goddamn amazing, but it is not yet available unluckily! Please [reach the author](http://mailto:info@marko-editor.com) if you are interested too!*

### [Zim Desktop Wiki](http://zim-wiki.org/)

[image: Zim Desktop Wiki]

[Zim sourcecode repository](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ejaap.karssenberg/zim/pyzim/files)

Disclaimer: the following review is a bit biased as I am regularly using this software.

```
Opensource (GPL2)
Win + Linux + Mac + BSD (runs on Python + GTK2, should be adaptable to any platform supported by GTK2)
Inline previewing (can type wiki markup code and it's styled on-the-fly) + WYSIWYG
Note-taking oriented (multi-documents)
Notes syntax and stored in hybrid DocuWiki/Markdown "lightweight" markup
Can export/copy snippet, single or all notes to standard Markdown
TOC navigation (plugin)
Very mature project (started in 2007, 9 years of development) and still active development (as of 2016)
Multi-documents tabs (with memorization of the order you opened them)
Autosaving per character (aka realtime autosaving)
Tags, pictures, can attach files alongside notes, calendar, etc.
Can copy/paste pictures from Paint or similar directly into a note (and can afterward resize) - such pictures will be stored inside your Zim notes folder
Clickable links
Remember last cursor position for every notes
LaTeX math formulas support (can be later edited by right-click)
Reorderable tables (markdown syntax) support
```

Also, lots of plugins, included natively in the app ([take a look](http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Plugins.html), they are all amazing, can even interface with GNOME's Zeitgeist, Lilypond music sheet, draw ASCII diagrams, etc). Here are a few I advise:

- Support for multi-users editing or cloud storage (dropbox etc) with 3-way diff (automatic and manual) with [this PR](https://github.com/zim-desktop-wiki/zim-desktop-wiki/pull/178).
- Support for bibliography and citation with the [zim-zotero plugin](https://github.com/shivams/zim-zotero-plugin).

Cons:

```
No Markdown support for storing the files (can only import/export to Markdown, but otherwise the notes are stored as Zim markup language). UPDATE 2020: there is now a markdown-zim bidirectional converter: [markdown2zim][33]. This can be used to migrate to/from other markdown editors.
```

/UPDATE 2018: to get instant refresh for all markups (like bold, italic, etc.), you need to enable the option "Reformat wiki markup on the fly" in the Editing panel of Preferences.

- Personal note: I am using Zim + Typora until something like Abricotine matures enough to be used for serious multi note taking* - UPDATE: I now use Zim + MarkText, and I may migrate to Zettlr.

### [Collate](https://collatenotes.com/welcome/)

[image: CollateNotes screenshot]

Collate (aka CollateNotes) is a note manager with an integrated Markdown editor mixed with YAML to store metadata. It has live rendering and editing abilities.

```
Everything is stored on local computer.
Made with crossplatform compatibility as a requirement (Windows, Mac, Linux).
Supports syntax highlighting for most languages.
Support for Github Flavored Markdown
Clear file format specification: https://github.com/Collateapp/CollateFileFormat
Tags
Commercial software, free trial for 14 days.
```

---

## Inline formatting/styling

The following editors won't provide a full Markdown inline preview, but they provide a prototype formatting/styling of your document. This allows you to somewhat know what your document will look like, even if some elements may not be correctly styled (or previewed at all like images). They also all provide a split-pane or a separated window for a full preview.

Note: inline styling is NOT just a simple regex in a code editor (such as Notepad++, SublimeText, Atom, etc.), because they cannot differenciate between different markup depths (eg, all headers levels are shown with the same styling), hence, they are excluded here.

### [Writer Plus (WriterP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsdwTZkB-x8)

[image: Writer Plus (WriterP)]

```
Freeware
Android
Stores each note as its own .md file directly in a Writer folder at the root of SD card (ease backups)
Easy to share notes by email (either directly as the email text content, or as attachment)
Probably a sequel to [Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamesmc.writer&hl=fr)
```

Note: I used this to replace ColorNotes, which stores notes in a database that is difficult to access and is [prone to data loss](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35207/import-data-from-colornote-app/92756). I use this one since years now instead and never lost a note since I back them up along with photos and other materials regularly.

### [iA Writer](https://ia.net/writer/support/windows)

[image: iA Writer]

```
Commercial
Cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Android, iOS)
Synchronization between devices
```

Note: it looks to me to be similar to Writer Plus, if I was using an iPhone or iPad, this is probably what I would be using.

### [Mou](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625100000/http://mouapp.com/) (archive.org)

[image: Mou]

```
Commercial
MacOSX
```

### [CuteMarked](https://cloose.github.io/CuteMarkEd/)

[image: CuteMarked]

```
Opensource
Win + Linux
TOC navigation
```

Note: Seems like this software is not maintained anymore.

### [Springseed](https://github.com/spsdco/notes)

[image: Springseed]

```
Opensource
Linux (+ Win in the future)
Note-taking oriented (multi-documents)
Preview when saving the document
```

Note: seems to be unmaintained since a few years now (the official website is dead, only the github remains).

### [TextNutWriter](http://www.textnutwriter.com/)

[image: TextNutWriter]

```
Commercial
Mac
Sourcecode/preview switching + WYSIWYG
```

### [QOwnNotes](http://www.qownnotes.org/)

[image: QOwnNotes]

```
Opensource (GPL)
Win + Mac + Linux
Inline styling/formatting
Note-taking oriented (multi-documents)
Said to be an equivalent to Quiver
Multi-documents tabs
Support for encrypted notes
Make your ownCloud (+ web editor supports inline styling)
Support for versioning
```

### [Metanota](http://www.metanota.com/)

[image: Metanota]

```
Freeware (with ads) or commercial
Mac
Seems to support inline previewing
Note-taking oriented (multi-documents)
```

### Web-based apps with inline styling/formatting

- [TOASTUI.editor](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.editor), a new kid in the block, WYSIWYG editor with CommonMark and GithubFlavoredMarkdown support, and also copy-paste from external spreadsheets and images. [If you are a JS developer, feel free to help!](https://www.reddit.com/r/opensource/comments/7nl7m5/markdown_wysiwyg_editor_help_wanted/?st=jc64v6aw&sh=ffde336a)
  [image: TUI.editor]
- [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor)

### [YodaNote](http://www.yodanote.com/)

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsdwTZkB-x8)

```
Freeware
Win + Android
Purports to support Markdown, but I couldn't find how
Note-taking oriented (multi-documents)
Stores in HTML by default, not Markdown
```

Comment: Maybe you should have provided one answer per tool. Like that we'd be able to vote appropriately. So over time we'll find which application is better than another. Like it is now, I'd want to upvote 5 times and downvote 3 times, so what should I do?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Lol you're right, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I thought about it but I don't know then where to place the categories descriptions, and I think that having these categories clarifies a lot the different kinds of editors and their usage. Any advice?

Comment: The non-markdown section does not fit the question. You could ask a separate question for this kind of programs and answer it yourself.

Comment: You can also ask for guidance on Meta. I'm also not too sure on how to continue with it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thank you for the input. In fact, most apps in the third category are using Markdown, I will need to think of a better way to name this category. I will also see about Meta, thank's.

Comment: Great post! The inline preview are exactly the ones I was looking for. But in reviewing some of them, I too think that you should've posted them all as separate answers so I could up/down vote them on their individual merit, maybe point out their shortcomings in the respective comments section. About the categories, you can mention them on each answer, maybe put the longer description in just one of the answers and link to that in the other answers where you simply mention the category by name.

Comment: @laggingreflex Glad my recs meet your needs! Good idea to put the long description in one answer and link in all the others, I wanted to do it, but the problem is that other answers already mention some of the softwares here, but without the bigger context (categories, list of features, demo gif). For example Texts.io. What should I do?

Comment: I skimmed through some meta posts relating to this issue: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112084/202302) [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114545/202302#comment298115_114545) [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202910/202302). It seems to me that you should either edit the existing answers, adding your info (and leave it up to the reviewers to decide whether it was worth the edit. I personally would definitely consider it so), or if that doesn't work out you can add a duplicate answer anyway, as long as it adds more info. Hope that helps. You can always ask on meta when in doubt.

Comment: @laggingreflex I already [posted on Meta software recs](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/only-one-software-recommandation-per-answer), and what transpired is that this is still in debate (voting for a recommendation vs voting for a product). About editing other answers, this is usually disadvised from the links you gave, and posting duplicates isn't that great but should be acceptable if I add more info. I will think about it, thank you.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Given how much I've searched for things like this, I'm awed that you have long existing and stable tools that appear to meet my needs.

Comment: Epic answer! And unlike most of the answers here, it even successfully incorporates the requirement that the Markdown be rendered in the same pane as the input. Yeah, this format doesn't allow us to vote for individual editors, but it's still a very useful answer.

Comment: Hm. I still think this is a valuable answer, but I am noticing that some of the images don't really illustrate how the software meets even the "in-line prototype styling" requirement. In particular, GitBook Editor looks like its in-line styling is no better than "simple regex" like Atom, which you rejected. And the Springseed picture gives pretty much no information at all about previewing capabilities. Maybe it's time for another update?

Comment: @JohnY About regex, it can be spotted as it cannot differenciate different headers depth, and thus render all headers with the same weight/font (I guess this can be fixed but then there will be other issues, a regex is not a reliable syntax processor). GitBook Editor can differenciate between headers depths and other kind of tricky markup such as quoting, but I did not dig too much, so it may lack more advanced markdown elements. About springseed, you may be right, but the development is dead, so I cannot try on Windows (Linux only for now), I still leave it in the list but added a mention.

Comment: @gaborous: Thanks for the effort put into this answer! Could you please split into separate answers, so that we can vote on each answer separately? That means more points for you ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @gaborous - GitBook Editor does **not** differentiate between header depths in the **in-line** styling. Therefore, it is no better than Atom in that regard. Notice that basically every Markdown editor in existence that has any kind of WYSIWYG preview at all (which includes Atom, if you allow plug-ins) will differentiate header depths in the WYSIWYG pane.

Comment: @JohnY You are correct, thank you for the feedback! I removed GitBookEditor from the list. at Nicolas Raoul: you are right but I feel it will only be more confusing to remove the categories, and having the categories explanation in a separate post would also be confusing I think. I prefer a nice compiled answer rather than having more points :-)

Comment: CuteMarked seems no longer maintained (no code for 2 years)

Comment: Does anyone know a tool like Typora for example that uses HTML instead of markdown as underlying source with live rendering view? Why are editors utilizing markdown instead of something like HTML which provides more features out-of-the box?

Comment: @Maikkeyy I'm not sure but you may have a look at MarkText and Apricotine, both use Electron and may render Markdown as HTML in their interface, but you need to check their sourcecode (both are opensource, MarkText is under a more active development though).

Comment: What an epic answer! I second others in placing each in separate answers or finding a place such that we can rank them.

Comment: **`Mou`** appears to be **discontinued**. _Last downloadable version was 0.8.7 (for OS X 10.7 to 10.11) released 2014._ Not currently available in the App Store. (P.S. would prefers if individual apps would individual answers for separate voting and comment.)

Answer (score 19):

### [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/)

It displays a live view on the right side. You can see a [full list of features on the website](http://markdownpad.com/compare.html).

[image: Screenshto of MarkdownPad]

Source: http://markdownpad.com/

**Note**

When starting MarkdownPad for the first time, it asks whether you want to buy the Pro version or use the free one. You can just click on "Use free" and it will never ask you again.

Comment: In any case, I deleted it very soon as trying it out. It's really really slow to respond.

Comment: Disappointment for me was it only supports "basic Markdown" – things like "Github flavored" or "Markdown Extra" are only available in the paid version (~USD 15 currently).

Comment: @Izzy Every Windows markdown editor I tried supported basic Markdown only. When someone adds extra nice features for a little money, people complain as if software developers should offer all their labor for free. Must be some Linux user mentality expecting all software to be free. Btw, this is a Windows question.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich see [my answer recommending ReText](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6777/185). Supports MarkdownExtra, MathJax etc. and comes for free.

Comment: Usually free open source apps are unpolished ganky apps. Sometimes with little and delayed support. The day when I need those features I will decide if it's worth the hassle to install Python, deal with such an app or just pay the $15 and get a commercial polished hand by hand supported app. It depends on one's tolerance and time cost. Thanks for the info.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Does *not* work on Windows 10, and hasn't been updated in more than two years

Comment: @rahuldottech - It *does* work on Windows 10, but requires an additional download. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791082/mardownpad-crashes-on-windows-10) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/954091/markdownpad-preview-fails-on-windows-10) for tips and commentary.

Comment: @JohnY Neat, but it sucks that the software hasn't been updated in three years...

Answer (score 15):

I'm using **[ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext)** for that. It's written in Python, so it should be cross-platform; in the project Wiki you can find detailed instructions on [how to install ReText on Windows](https://github.com/retext-project/retext/wiki/Installing-ReText#for-users-of-windows-and-macos), as that's the platform you're using.

*ReText* does a great job for me on Linux. Supports a lot of "specific dialects" in addition to standard Markdown, like Michel Fortins [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/), [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), and many more. You can export your texts as HTML, ODT (Open Document Text, i.e. for OpenOffice/LibreOffice), PDF.

And: next to a "preview button", it also provides a Live Preview, side by side, while you're typing:

[image: ReText with Live Preview]
<sup>*ReText* with Live Preview (source: ReText; click image for larger variant)</sup>

I'm using this for a while now, and it's running stable, smooth, and fast. With support for mentioned "dialects" (I'm pretty sure I saw somewhere it also support the dialects in use here at SE, and the one from GitHub), I can only heartly recommend it to you!

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your Windows OS has a browser, and you can find at least briefly a working Internet connection, you can use [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)

[image: screenshot of StackEdit]

StackEdit features:

- Works offline - documents are saved in your browser's local storage, and can be opened from and saved to your local filesystem. Once loaded, the app's code is cached by your browser, and will open and work just fine with zero Internet connectivity.
- Real-time preview
- Support for standard Markdown
- Support for [Markdown Extra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown_Extra)
- Support for *exporting* documents as raw Markdown (text), HTML or PDF
- Support for saving and *synchronizing* a document with Dropbox or Google Drive
- Support for *publishing* a document to Blogger, Dropbox, Gist, GitHub, Google Drive, Tumblr, WordPress or any SSH server.

Not that while this *does* offer a live, synchronized preview rendering, and *attempts* to style the source based on the markup being edited, **it does not allow editing of the preview itself** - whether or not the styled editor is sufficient for your requirements I cannot say.

Comment: I've noticed that StackEdit doesn't support some HTML5 syntax.

Comment: Is there a portable version for Windows or is the only offline-capable version a Chrome app?

Comment: @SarahofGaia: this is the only version that's there. But your question made me think and I think you can make a standalone version using [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/)

Comment: "But your question made me think" Lol glad to be of service. ;3

Comment: Also, thanks for the link. But not only am I too inexperienced to work with something like that (it *looks* advanced, at least), and it's still in beta. As a general principle, unless I **really** want or need to use a programme, I don't use them if they're still in beta or prior.

Comment: It may be worth updating this answer, since the edit pane seems to have more advanced styling than what is shown in the picture here. Notably, it does show the various heading levels in different sizes.

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative you can choose is **[Github Atom](https://atom.io)**.

Since nobody mentioned it, I give you the alternative editor which I use every time when I am working on a project. **Github Atom** is not only Markdown editor but also like other editor — text editor — but, you can hack the core. Answering your question, this editor supports live preview what you write on Markdown. The live preview is called **Markdown Preview**, one of the packages is included by default on fresh Github Atom you install. See how it works below:

[image: Github Atom UI]

The example I show to you is some dummy texts on Markdown. The way you can get it is very simple: **write** your Markdown text and **press** `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `M`, then another pane will show the result even your live editing.

Github Atom is free and open source, available for Windows. You can download it [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases) by downloading the executable file one. Feel free to ask if you have something to say.

Comment: Also check out the more powerful [Markdown Preview Plus](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-plus) and [language-pfm](https://atom.io/packages/language-pfm) plugins.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin thank you so much for the addition.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>I very strongly suspect there aren't any editors specifically like that.</strike>(edit: I stand corrected @Izzy) However with a bit of plugin and external software installation you can have [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) do that.

The result will look like this:
[image]
(from the author as I'm not going to be able to do better than that to show how good it is)

So the (unfortunately a *little* bit complicated) setup/install instructions: (These instructions are for windows, but it should also work on Mac, however, there will be a few differences - like you won't need the Windows SDK but you might need something else and stuff like that)

1. Install [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).
2. Install [Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases).
3. Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).
4. (You can try to step 5 without this from the normal cmd line and it may work depending on your installed tools/path) Install [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8279) . It'll work on any thing XP+. Windows SDK 8 won't work - doesn't include all the tools so you have to install that and a compiler. If you have the VS 2010 redistributables installed already try unchecking them in the installer for the Windows SDK - otherwise, you may have to uninstall them to be able to install this and then reinstall the newer version if you need to at some point.
5. Install Node.JS package [Markmon](https://github.com/yyjhao/markmon) - best to just type in a the Windows SDK Build Environment cmd prompt `npm install -g markmon`.
6. Install SublimeText [PackageControl plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation).
7. Install the SublimeText [Markmon plugin](https://github.com/yyjhao/sublime-text-markmon). <strike>**BUT NOT according to the instructions there as currently that won't work for Windows - hopefully it will soon** (ie when my fork is merged). Instead, you'll have to [install from my fork] where I've fixed it to work on Windows. So you'll have to download that to your SublimeText Packages folder (usually `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`).</strike>  **My edits now merged so just follow the page's instruction and then in SublimeEdit go to Preferences->Package Settings->Markmon->Settings - User and edit the file to at least have this for settings:

   {
       "executable": "markmon.cmd",
   }
8. Restart SublimeText and run Tools->Markmon->Launch

Rendered markdown will appear *live* as you edit it in SublimeText in a new browser window. You can position them side by side to make it work pretty good.

(Note: I had no previous connection to this project but to write up this answer I, of course, had to use it and then I discovered it didn't work on Windows so I have now forked it and submitted a pull request to fix that)

Answer (score 9):

Texts does do it and is available for Windows and MacOs. http://www.texts.io

[image: Text inline editing Screenshot]

Comment: This is the only one that has inbuilt live viewer that I really want. Unfortunately its Markdown-processing is very sub-par and heavily customized for the app. You can't copy-paste stuff from here to this app and back without inconsistencies.

Comment: There have since been a couple more answers that offer editors which render the Markdown *in the same pane as the input, as you type*. But yeah, almost all the answers miss this critical part of your question.

Answer (score 7):

**[Haroopad](https://github.com/rhiokim/haroopad)** is a cross-platform (Linux, OSX, Windows) Markdown editor GUI based on NodeJS that includes a live preview pane. In a lot of ways, it is similar to the Atom editor (in fact I suspect they share some node libraries) but the interface is tailored specifically for dealing with Markdown documents.

[image: screenshot]

The preview pane updates in nearly real time (although I don't think it's quite as responsive as some others I've tried) and does a good job of rendering Markdown as you would expect it to appear. You can choose from several style sheets for the preview or load your own CSS (e.g. you can load you site's CSS stylesheet so the preview looks exactly like the content will render is your site!).

The editor can also be styled using CSS, includes keybindings and optional auto-complete for common Markdown formatting, and has a full blown VIM mode for the truly savvy.

Optional Markdown parsing features include:

- Github flavored markdown
- Whether to parse inline HTML elements
- "Smart" typographic features like quotes and dashes
- Footnotes (would that SE included this!)
- Mathjax/LaTex style expressions

The integration between the two works about like you'd expect with synchronized scroll of the preview while moving around in the editor. Extras include a sidebar with Markdown syntax hints and an insert menu for when you can't remember how something goes. Besides the usual saving in Markdown format, it can also export to HTML or send the rendered version of documents via email.

Comment: Just a few questions: (1) Is it lightweight? (2) Does it have a portable version? (3) Is it open-source? (4) You said it has "Smart" typographic features like quotes and dashes: does this mean it can use curly quotes? (5) And what do you mean by "smart" dashes: em/en dashes?

Comment: @SarahofGaia 2: none found. 3: claims to be(come), is hosted at Github. Smart dashes: auto-converts "--" (two "minus") to "–" (dash) in viewer. // What I strongly miss are tabs; Haroopad uses one window per file, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. Haroopad was my editor for ~2 years now. But it's so buggy (even Copy/Paste does not work) and no longer maintained (last commit 2 years ago). It does not respect window docking (on Windows 10). It claims "Github flavored", it will not detect links that are broken because of missing %20 spaces.

Answer (score 6):

I've been asking this question for a long time now too. I use this: [Pen -- what you see is what you get](http://sofish.github.io/pen/).

[image: As you type, your text will be formatted]

It's probably not as full-featured as other solutions, but I really appreciate  that I can style in the same window.
Hope this helps.

NOTE: It's a little buggy, not sure if it would fit your needs. But I do have to point out, it has potential.

Comment: Nice one, reminds me of http://abricotine.brrd.fr/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a new Markdown Editor for Windows to check out.

http://mike-ward.net/markdownedit

[image: screen shot]

It has a built-in preview as you requested plus most of the other features one would expect like:

- as you type spell checking
- full-screen mode
- quick recent documents window
- find and replace with regular expressions
- keyboard shortcuts for common Markdown expressions
- Themes
- CommonMark (a proposed standard for Markdown)
- Paste special replaces MS Word characters with plain text (quotes for instance)
- Synchronized scrolling

Markdown Edit places the emphasis on content and keyboard shortcuts. Menus and status bars are minimal and subtle.

`Full disclosure: I'm the developer`

Comment: I'd like to commend you for stating that disclosure. It was a very honourable act. *bows* I respect that. :)

Comment: Just checked it out via the website: it looks great! But is there a portable version of this? :/

Comment: I've never tried this but I think if you copy the folder (in App_Data/local) to a thumb drive it should work. The host computer still needs .Net installed however.

Comment: Most modern forms of Windows have .net installed by default, right? Win7, 8, and 10?

Comment: Later versions yes. Earlier versions not so much.

Comment: Win7 does, right? I have SP1.

Comment: If not, go to http://smallestdotnet.com/ and click the `Get .NET` button to install.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I could check if I have it installed? Also, aren't there multiple versions of .NET?

Comment: http://smallestdotnet.com has a test application.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free [Markdown Editor plugin for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/markdown-text-editor) that has a preview window:

[image: Markdown Editor plugin UI]

Comment: Isn't this already posted above? :/

Comment: @SarahofGaia Good point, I must have missed it. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. ^_^

Comment: What exactly is Eclipse?

Comment: @SarahofGaia An IDE: https://eclipse.org/

Comment: Does this community allow / prefer multiple recommendations in one answer?  I also like Typora, so I've given an up vote.  If you remove Typora and we enter it as it's own answer, I'll migrate my vote to the new answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Markdown Notes](http://markdownnotes.com) would fit your needs. There is a live demo on the front page if you want to use it just as an editor. There are also some features such as image uploads and LaTeX support that are not available in every markdown editor.

[image: Markdown Notes UI]

Comment: Just checked out the website. This editor looks amazing! But my question is this: it doesn't look like it's anything more than a webapp; is this something I can use offline? Is there a installable or portable version of it?

Comment: Also, can you use it for using markdown on full-length documents or is it only best for notetaking?

Comment: It's strictly an online editor, but it can handle some pretty heavy documents. I used it to create lengthy, latex-heavy cheat sheets and it handles it pretty well.

Comment: Aww man I really would love an offline one. Still, I might check it out on my Google Crapbook. ;P How's it stack up (see what I did there?) against [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io/)?

Answer (score 2):

It's strange but there is no answer about great, free and open-source [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

[image: Visual Studio Code Window]

VS Code supports highlighting, live preview, header folding, and other Markdown features (see an [official description](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown)).

Moreover, there are plenty of markdown plugins that improve productivity: [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker), [MarkdownLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint), [Table Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shuworks.vscode-table-formatter), [Markdown TOC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlanWalk.markdown-toc) and [other](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=markdown&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the requirement that the styling occurs directly in the editing area. That was pretty much the whole point of this question. It is true that most of the other answers here fail in the same way, so I can't really blame you for suggesting it. Still, I wish people would actually stick to the requirements if possible.

Comment: @JohnY what exactly don't you like in my answer? You can edit it by yourself.

Comment: Your answer does not need editing. It is not a badly written answer. But your answer is a *wrong* answer because the software you are recommending does not do what the question is asking for. Most of the answers here are wrong for the same reason.

Comment: I read the question title again. You are right, my answer does not correspond the header. Sorry, sprinkle my head with ashes.

Answer (score 1):

StackEdit actually has an offline Chrome app as well, meaning it can be used as a  cross platform Markdown editor. It's built on the same stuff as Stack Exchange, so the experience is similar to that.

If you're looking for something that integrates the Markdown output in the same pane, I'd look at [Qute](http://www.inkcode.net/qute), which is a Markdown editor for Windows/Mac that lets you edit individual paragraphs as Markdown then switches them back to preview.

There's also a [List of 78 Markdown editors](http://mashable.com/2013/06/24/markdown-tools/) that might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-homepage-vs.aspx) has a plugin [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) that provides markdown syntax highlighting and preview. It's a good choice if you're going to be slinging code along with your markdown.

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend Zerk.tk? It's extremely simple to use with just an editor and a viewer, nothing else. It has one export feature that exports directly to GitHub Gists. It's a web app but you could [clone the repo](https://github.com/xrisk/zerk) to download it for offline use.

## [Zerk](https://Zerk.tk) ([Github Repo](https://github.com/xrisk/zerk))

> A simple markdown REPL, nothing more.
>
> Fully in-browser with zero server-side processing.
>
> [image: Zerk UI]

Note: I helped develop zerk

Answer (score 1):

I found one which is nice, but does not add things like:

:warning:  as emojis

name: [zettlr](https://github.com/Zettlr/Zettlr)

[image: another markdwon editor zettlr]

Comment: Can you add the relevant link to the suggested program?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 there is another alternative which is [BookPad](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/bookpad/9n6p5zh2sjsx), you can find it in the Store. It is an offline markdown editor but supports a lot of the extra syntax. The out put is beautiful.

It has a price currently of $0.99

Comment: I just checked the price; it has gone up to $1.99.