# Free Markdown editor for Windows with tabs, live-view, tables

Tags: windows, gratis, markdown

This question is closely related to [Markdown editor for Windows with inbuilt live viewer inside the editor itself](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5746/185), but has some additional requirements:

- Must run on Windows (cross-platform welcome)
- should be free (as in "free beer"), preferably open-source (free as in "free speech"), permit use in commercial context (internal office use)
- Must support at least Markdown Extra or Github-flavored Markdown
- strongly preferred: supporting Markdown Extra including its "special attributes" (like `## Header { .class }` – most editors have issues with the `{ .class }` part here)
- support for tabs (I don't want separate windows for each document)
- live preview (2-pane preferred)
- native (no web-app)
- preferably has a portable version available, but at least must be easy to install without much fuss/dependencies/bloat (I don't own the machine this must run on) and work behind a firewall (even if the computer has no internet access)
- preferably light-weight (I don't want to download 50MB+ just for an editor and have it occupy 100MB+ of disk space when installed)
- nice-to-have: Export functionality (PDF/ODF/HTML/Word)

From the linked question, no answer fits all these requirements (well, the question didn't have these requirements):

- [MarkdownPad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10177/185) comes pretty close, but lacks support for any Markdown "dialect" in its free version (Markdown Extra / Github-flavored require buying the pro version for ~USD 15)
- [Haroopad](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10138/185) comes close but lacks tabs, so one *must* use separate windows for each document
- [ReText](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6777/185) would almost make me happy, but is not easy to install (dependencies etc.)
- [SublimeText](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/5778/185) has far too many dependencies
- [Atom](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23050/185) has issues previewing Markdown-Extra (tried that on Linux at home; but AFAIK all the above have this issue with Markdown-Extra's attributes like `## Header { .class }`, so I might give this one another try). Also, in order to install the required packages, it requires internet access. I wasn't able to get that working, even providing proxy settings (portable version).
- most other answers are web-apps (no option here) or do not match multiple criteria given above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **[MarkPad](http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/)**:

- Runs on Windows (8.1 or 10; will not run on Windows 7!)
- Free and open source
- Markdown Extra support
- Support for tabs
- Live preview (2-pane)
- Written in C# (.NET)

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (source: [Markpad](http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/))</sup>

Markdown-Extra must be explicitly turned on in settings. *Markpad* loads fast (a log faster than *Atom.io* – and even a little faster than *Haroopad*), and comes with a nice 2-panel preview enabled by default. Built-in help is nice, using Markdown itself :)

*Markpad* might need some getting used to, but it's definitely simple and fast (though not exactly light-weight with 50 MB installed, and not that customizable).

An installer can be downloaded at the projects homepage, which then downloads another ~50 MB to complete the installation. For installation without internet connection (e.g. using an USB stick), I've made a [full compile available in my Google Drive account](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PfeC2GOy6SNWpWUXNWOFNzN2c/view?pref=2&pli=1) – which can simply be unzipped into the desired location for "portable installation".<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>**1:** if you don't trust that, you can compile it yourself using Visual Studio</sup>

Comment: Hm, uses a kind of web installer it seems? How to install that on an "isolated computer" that shouldn't access the network itself? Is there a portable version anywhere?

Comment: @Izzy if you have Visual Studio on another computer, you can compile it yourself and copy the build with an USB stick to the isolated computer...

Comment: Too much fuss (the compiling part, mainly) :) But thanks nevertheless!

Comment: @Izzy I compiled it for you: http://tinyurl.com/markpad-zip

Comment: Thanks, leaving me no choice, are you? :) OK, tried it. Markdown-Extra must be explicitly turned on in settings (OK with me). Loads fast (a log faster than Atom.io – and even a little faster than Haroopad), I like its 2-panel preview better than the one from Atom. Built-in help is nice, using Markdown itself :) Needs getting used to, but definitely simple and fast (though not exactly light-weight with 50 MB installed, and not that customizeable). Still, seems to match the requirements from the question :) Thanks, +1 – and hope you like my edit :)

Comment: Ironically, activity on the project has ceased at roughly the same time you answered the question :-) That is, there is no activity since about 6 years now.