# Markdown parser and editor for nodejs

Tags: node.js, html-editor, markdown, parser

I am looking for a node.js markdown parser and editor with the following features:

- conversion to

  - html
  - pdf
- support of

  - basic md syntax
  - mathjax equations
  - tables
  - file attachments
- a HTML embeddable editor, which

  - is wysiwyg or at least has preview
  - is extendable (e.g. I want to add a mathjax calculator, to evaluate equations automatically)
  - uses the same parser

Comment: While waiting for answers, you might wish to check [related questions with answers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[markdown]+editor+answers%3A1) – currently there are 12 on Markdown editors. I bet a few of the answers [have one for NodeJS](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10138/185) :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks! I'll check it. I have a list of md parsers, maybe some of them has an editor as well: https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js https://github.com/andris9/node-markdown https://github.com/chjj/marked https://github.com/rhiokim/haroopad It's (not) funny that people write markdown to HTML converters, but they don't provide GUI based editors which use these libs. I get that markdown is about writing text, instead of using a GUI, but to me it is just a format I can save and version documents on server side and regular users like wysiwyg editors.

Comment: Well, there're plenty of MD editors around, all kind of flavors. So many that you easily can lose track of them :)

Comment: @Izzy Yes, but they are slightly different from each other in the parser, that's why I want to use the same markdown parser on server and in the editor on the client. So there won't be unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Understandable. But the most important part of that is the "flavor". They all support "Standard MD", and most add one or more "flavors" to be supported: SO, Github, Markdown Extra … If you've covered that part, you've covered 99% already.