# HTML variants of desktop markdown editors?

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm currently using Typora as a markdown editor for keeping my notes. I really like the live rendering feature of it and that it does support **HTML**. I have been searching a lot for the best app for organizing my notes on Linux and Typora is the one that came the closest, but I'm still asking myself if there are any other Linux desktop apps that work like CKEditor for example.

CKEditor is exactly what I would like as an desktop app. I like the toolbar in it, so you don't have to remember shortcuts. Is there such an app like this? Much e-mail clients do have this feature of having a toolbar for markup and if you want you can paste in real HTML, but is there also an desktop app for notes that takes this approach?

So, basically I want:

- A desktop HTML editor instead of a markdown editor
- Live rendering feature instead of preview (no splitted views, just one live render view)
- Toolbar for formatting

Why are the most apps using markdown as they could simply also use html as underlying source as it provides much more features? CKEditor is exactly what I want as it provides the real-time rendering of HTML without a preview, but I want one for the desktop as well for managing notes.

[image: want]

I want exactly this feature, but instead an app that utilizes HTML as underlying source: [Markdown editor for Windows with live rendering in the editing pane, NOT in a separate preview pane](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/markdown-editor-for-windows-with-live-rendering-in-the-editing-pane-not-in-a-se/6777)

Comment: VSCode/VSCodium with `yzhang.markdown-all-in-one` (Markdown all in one extension) may fit the bill ...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at [RedNotebook](https://rednotebook.sourceforge.io/)

- Windows, **Linux** & OS/X
- Insert #hashtags
- Format text bold, italic or underlined
- Insert images, files and links
- Spell check
- Search-as-you-type
- Automatic saving
- Backup to zip archive
- Word clouds with most common words and tags
- Templates
- Export to plain text, HTML or Latex
- Future-proof: data is stored in plain text files
- Private: you own your data
- Translated into more than 30 languages

Comment: I did install it, but it hasn't got the feature of live rendering the styles applied. It has splitted views for editing. Thanks for your reply though, as it is a nice compact note editor :).