# A good editor for technical tutorials on Mac?

Tags: osx, text-editor, html, markdown

I write a lot of tutorials and publish them as HTML. Usually, I type them directly in HTML but each time I use `<code>` tags to show a code example, I have to manually update the content of the tags (for example, changing `>` to `&gt;`).

Currently, I'm using TextMate 2 but am looking for a more efficient way to do this on Mac. How would you approach it (markdown?) and which software would you use?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need import/export to/from HTML format?

Comment: Export to HTML, yes. As per my answer, Mou does it perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. After evaluating both, I chose to use Markdown for writing the lessons, using [Mou](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625100000/http://mouapp.com/) as a text editor. It does everything I need, is free and then allows me to `copy to HTML`.

Comment: **`Mou`** appears to be **discontinued**. Last downloadable version was 0.8.7 (for OS X 10.7 to 10.11) released 2014. Not currently available in the App Store.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you **[ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext)**, as outlined in [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6777/185):

[image: ReText with Live Preview]
<sup>*ReText* with Live Preview (source: ReText; click image for larger variant)</sup>

- Since [release 7.0](https://github.com/retext-project/retext/blob/master/changelog.md#retext-70-2017-02-11), it is possible to install ReText on macOS using a `pip3 install ReText` command.
- It features a live preview, so you see the results of what you're typing while you're typing
- It supports a bunch of dialect and other addons, such as "codelite" for code highlighting
- No fiddling with HTML (except if you wish for), but using Markdown (as used here on SE)
- It can export your texts as HTML, ODT (Open Document Text, i.e. for OpenOffice/LibreOffice), PDF

I use it myself for a while now, and am quite pleased with it: smooth and stable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [**MacDown**](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/). It works on macOS Sierra, where [Mou](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625100000/http://mouapp.com/) does not. It's ideal editor for developers, such as technical tutorials, since it supports syntax highlighting (by enabling *Syntax highlighted code block* in the *Rendering Preference pane*). Here is the full list of [Supported Code Block Syntaxes](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/features/code-block-highlighting/). The software is open source, free to use and released under MIT License.

[image: MacDown, Markdown editor for macOS]

Related: [Markdown editor for OSX that includes a preview, ideally in real time?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25/3474)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using doing your document editing in restructured text, *rst*, and using a tool such as [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to produce the final version(s).

This will allow you to minimise your working files, in a nice version control suitable format while producing output in any or all of:
asciidoc, beamer, context, docbook, docx, dzslides, epub, epub3, fb2, html, html5, json, latex, man, markdown, markdown_github,  markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki, native, odt, opendocument, opml, org, pdf*, plain, revealjs, rst, rtf, s5, slideous, slidy, texinfo, textile.

Answer (score 1):

## AsciiDoc

[Dr. Matt Neuburg](http://www.apeth.net/matt/default.html), one of the best technical writers alive, turns out [enormous tomes](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/249#Books) using [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) ([Wikipedia article](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/)) and any favorite text editor. AsciiDoc is similar to [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), and is semantically equivalent to [DocBook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook) [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Read [his blog post](http://www.apeth.net/matt/iosbooktoolchain.html) explaining how he works.

AsciiDoc can output to various formats including including [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html), [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format), [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB), [man page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

Answer (score 0):

I use the web app [***StackEdit***](https://stackedit.io/editor) to manage blog posts, [Gist tutorials](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/7073558) and Stack Exchange answers. It is a markdown editor and has this relevant features:

- Works off-line
- Sync with Google Drive and Dropbox, ie, edit on Desktop and Tablet
- Publishing to the following services

  [image: blogger, github, wordpress, others]
- Export the formats

  [image: markdown, html, template, pdf]
- Copy the HTML directly from the editor

  [image]