# Simple Markdown viewer for Ubuntu (standalone program, not something that requires usage of an internet browser)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, markdown, text

I am looking for a Markdown viewer. It should:

- run locally on Ubuntu - be a normal program, not a browser addon, webapp or anything else that requires usage of an internet browser*

Preferable:

- simple and lightweight
- open source

Viewer as in "view formatted content". It is fine if viewer is also an editor.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331281/how-can-i-test-what-my-readme-md-file-will-look-like-before-committing-to-github for wider version of this question.

*I give an exception to browsers running in terminal in text mode

Comment: I know you don't want anything which requires an internet browser. But may be you could check jupyter-lab. It has inbuilt markdown reader. VS code also has some extensions.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Though not strictly being a *viewer*, I can recommend **[ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext)** here – which I'm using myself on Ubuntu, and am pretty satisfied.

- **runs locally on Linux:** Yes (also on Windows and Mac)
- **normal program, not a browser addon:** Yes. Written in Python, and easy to deal with.
- **simple and lightweight:** Yes. On its own, it comes with the basics – and you can add more (like support for specific Markdown dialects as *[Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/)* or *[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)* if you need.
- **open source:** Yes (using GPLv2)

[image: ReText with Live Preview]
<sup>*ReText* with Live Preview (source: ReText; click image for larger variant)</sup>

As I said to start with, it's not strictly a viewer – but an editor including a viewer and a "Live Preview". You can call it from the command line, passing the file as parameter. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to start it directly in the viewer mode – but a work-around to at least have the "Live Preview" triggered:

- start it once with a file open
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (or use the menu: *Edit › Live Preview*) to switch on the "Live Preview" mode
- using the menu, go to *Edit › Preferences*, and check "Restore live preview state" under "Behavior"

Now, when opened the next time, the "Live Preview" is switched on automatically. Alternatively, you can open the "real preview" (without the editor pane) by either clicking the "Preview" button, or using the keyboard-shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.

For more details, also see my answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6777/185) and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6918/185).

Comment: You can even export to html pdf etc through Retext

Comment: On Ubuntu 16, a simple `apt-get install retext` will do the trick (then just invoke `retext` from the shell).

Comment: Same for Mint 18. But usually, the repos of distris often don't have the latest version (while currently the PPA still lacks the "xenial" branch ;)

Comment: Installation: `pip3 install retext --user`. On Ubuntu 18.04, don't do the installation with apt-get; it doesn't work: I can open the file, but the preview does not show up. Instead, I get warnings due to missing python packages. This doesn't happen when installed via `pip`.

Comment: I tried enabling Github-style syntax highlighting in code-blocks, following this section of the wiki: https://github.com/retext-project/retext/wiki/Markdown-extensions#third-party-extensions. Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: @ElouanKeryell-Even wrong place for troubleshooting here. That should rather happen in the issues "there" ;)

Comment: On Xubuntu 19.04 and with pip-installed retext, I had to `pip3 install PyQt5` for retext to work.

Comment: Not really working on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: ReText works for me as follows:

Comment: The padding in Retext's preview mode is dreadful.

Comment: ReText now has support for the `--preview` command line option to only show the preview

Answer (score 25):

## [Grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip)

I have been using this for a year and it is my goto Markdown render-er. Here are its features:

- **Markdown?** [Github](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) Flavored
- **Linux?** Yes
- **Normal?** Yes
- It is a command line tool
- **Offline?** No
- > There's also a [work-in-progress](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip/tree/offline-renderer) branch to provide offline rendering
- **Simple/Lightweight?** Yes
- It is a command line tool
- **Open source?** Yes

#### Bonus

- **Export** to PDF/HTML
- **Host** locally as a webpage/wiki
- **GitHub Auth** to increase API limit ([docs](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip?tab=readme-ov-file#access))

---

Here is an example of the HTML output.

[image]

Comment: I thought it works offline, because it starts a service on a local port, but this service inside connects remotely - I checked by taking the eth cable out ;)

Comment: A perfect example of "I can't believe this is not The answer"-syndrome that plagues SE sites.

Comment: `grip` requires use of a browser. So this is not the right answer.

Comment: Installed but not visible/openable on Apps array. Started it on CLI but just got a load of excuses about "lazy loading" . . . Rubbish as usual with Ubuntu MD readers.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret Feel free to open a separate question without "standalone program, not something that requires usage of an internet browser" requirement

Comment: It can be used on the CLI with a [headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers). Since the OP's vague requirement seems to exclude only GUI browsers, this answer is the best. I find that the online aspect of Grip is a lot more regrettable.

Comment: Works great, but it stopped working after a while: it uses Github API and it has a limit of 60 requests/hour! This limit should only be applicable without logging in, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to put my credentials for grip...

Comment: @ForeverLearning, I added a link (https://github.com/joeyespo/grip?tab=readme-ov-file#access) to the Bonus section above for GitHub Auth

Comment: Crap app that starts a server locally and has to be accessed by the browser. Stay away. Use obsidian

Answer (score 15):

## Okular

[image: Screenshot]

[Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) has a [Markdown backend](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdegraphics/okular/configure-backends.html#config-markdown), which allows it to display Markdown-formated text. On Debian-based systems (like Ubuntu) you might have to install the [okular-extra-backends](https://packages.debian.org/buster/okular-extra-backends) package to use it.

```
sudo apt install okular okular-extra-backends
```

The nice thing about Okular is that it is just a plain viewer. You can use your text editor of choice, and as soon as you save the Markdown document, Okular reloads the document.

Comment: At least for me Okular fails to line wrap, unlike other Markdown renderers.

Comment: @reducingactivity Did you report a bug? I'm running version 1.3.2 and it is wraps the lines just fine.

Comment: I am running 1.9.3(`okular -v`). I have not reported bug because I already have a good tool for this task and I am not planning to use Okular for that. Also, they link to some unusuable monotracker at https://okular.kde.org/contact.php

Comment: @reducingactivity I just have tested the version in the current Ubuntu LTS, which is 1.9.3. For my test examples, Okular was wrapping the text as it should.

Comment: The wrap issue that I experienced with version 1.3.3 (tied to Ubuntu 18.04) is when the text in the source file is indented by least two stops. This renders indented text, typeset as code, that is not wrapped; this may well be expected. If the indentation in the source file is removed, the text is typeset normally and gets wrapped as expected. The indentation in the source code may intrude because of a copy and paste, for example.

Answer (score 9):

Following is copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331281/how-can-i-test-what-my-readme-md-file-will-look-like-before-committing-to-github#40696607 by Brian Burns

> [**Atom**](https://atom.io/) works nicely out of the box - just open the Markdown file and hit **Ctrl+Shift+M** to toggle the Markdown preview panel next to it. It handles HTML and images also.
>
> [image: Atom screenshot]

Though note that performance of Atom is ridiculously poor and that development of that software appears to be stopping - see https://github.com/atom/atom/graphs/contributors (probably as it makes no sense to Microsoft to maintain two text editors in the same niche)

As of March 2023 Atom is officially dead.

Comment: The only disadvantage is Atom can be heavy if you want to edit/view Markdown files only.

Comment: I'll add that this plugin - https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-enhanced - is an excellent, full feature markdown addition that includes themes and link resolution, which the default markdown-preview doesn't currently support.

Comment: Atom ????????? Doubt if it's still alive.

Answer (score 9):

```
pandoc -s filename.md | lynx -stdin
```

This doesn't meet the requirement of "... or anything else that requires usage of browser", but the browser runs in a terminal in text mode.

https://pandoc.org/

Comment: I modified the question to allow in-terminal text mode browsers.

Answer (score 7):

What I generally do is run the markdown [perl script](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and save the resulting html in a temporary file that can be browsed using Firefox. For example:

`Markdown.pl index.md > index.html`

Answer (score 6):

I find Retext fine as is answered but I do have digged out a few MD editors for linux that are more or less better than the solution suggested.

If more they have additional features, and less so they are fast.

- [Haroopad](http://pad.haroopress.com/user.html) 
  This is more feature-filled than Remarkable, and looks like a dev tool.(The dev version of this app is also coming soon)
- [Springseed](https://github.com/byhestia/springseed) 
  If you needed a note taker This one does the job Beautifully.

Comment: It would be better to post each tool in a separate answer so that each answer can be voted on separately

Answer (score 5):

There is also an amazing one [here on GitHub](https://github.com/charmbracelet/glow/releases) appropriately named **Glow**... It's absolutely lightweight. You don't even need to leave the terminal. Works on Linux, Mac and Windows.

Here's a simple markdown text I created quickly to view with Glow. It only consists of an ordinary(non-marked-down) line of text, an H1 header, a horizontal rule, a block quote line, and a Python snippet:

````
I am not wrong!!!!!!!

# Can YOU handle it ????????

---

> Oh my goshhhhh!!!!!!

```python
print("Hello World")
```|
````

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Remarkable

Features:

- Live preview
- It's free.
- Extremely lightweight
- Export to HTML, PDF

  Download: https://remarkableapp.github.io/

Comment: Note that this project seems to be nearly abandoned - there are multiple waiting PRs (https://github.com/jamiemcg/Remarkable/pulls) despite claim "Work on Remarkable will resume soon" from January 2017 https://github.com/jamiemcg/Remarkable/commit/f9d72cab55e24a4c4bdc6bf826e04990f2be91f6

Comment: Unfortunately at this time Remarkable does not open the file when you right click & "open in remarkable".  It just opens/starts out with a blank.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 20.04, install from the bundled apt repos:

```
sudo apt install ghostwriter
```

Pros:

- bundled in official Ubuntu repos
- binary executable rather than a script

Cons:

- [on life support](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter) - not even [bug fixing PRs](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#pull-requests) are accepted and issue tracker is disabled.

[image: Image showing an example of a Ghostwriter rendering]

Comment: Not good enough, I think. Strange that a decent MD file viewer for Ubuntu just can't be found . . .

Answer (score 1):

## Brackets.io

[*Brackets*](http://brackets.io) is an open-source free-of-cost text editor sponsored by Adobe. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brackets_(text_editor)).

[image]

Live preview of HTML+CSS is built-in.

## *Markdown Preview* extension

➠ For live preview of [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), use the [*Markdown Preview*](https://github.com/gruehle/MarkdownPreview) extension by [gruehle](https://github.com/gruehle).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked in 2015. Meanwhile [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has become quite popular. It is available also on Linux.

VS Code has good [Markdown support built-in](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown), and since 2017 or so it has a Preview-Mode for Markdown (sync'ed split windows). For screenshots, scroll down on the page I've linked to.

Markdown support can also be enriched with many extensions, e.g. "markdownlint".

[image]

Comment: Would it be OK if I would add a screenshot?

Comment: yes, go ahead, good idea.

Answer (score 1):

### mdless

I found this one quite handy. It is a ruby gem, that allows CLI viewing of Markdown files.

if you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install ruby
sudo gem install mdless
```

https://brettterpstra.com/2015/08/21/mdless-better-markdown-in-terminal/

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple Note:

   is a note taking  and its accepting MarkDown

https://simplenote.com

2. Boostnote:

Another alternative and its what i am using.

https://boostnote.io/

Both are Totally Free..

Comment: SimpleNote won't open a MarkDown file if you double-click on it

Answer (score 1):

[abricotine](https://github.com/brrd/abricotine)

**Relevant Pros:**

- preview your document directly in the text editor rather than in a side pane (could be a cons but I find it a pro).
- supports inline images
- Write in markdown and export documents in HTML or in any other format supported by Pandoc (PDF, docx, ODT, etc.),
- Preview text elements (such as headers, images, math, embedded videos, todo lists...) while you type,
- Auto save your document on change (optional),
- Display document table of content in an optional side pane,
- Display syntax highlighting for code,
- and [many more](https://github.com/brrd/abricotine#features)

**Cons**

- yet to find (maybe not so light?)

Comment: Nice editor but not "simple and lightweight".

Comment: indeed, slightly on the heavy side (i find it simple to use though)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, It is very strange to me that [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) is not listed here. I have been using this tool for more than a year and I am quite happy with it.

I am using it without paying any subscription fees. I use git extension to save my notes to `Github` and I use `termux` in android to receive those updates.

However, you can use its premium service which has sync feature enable automatically for you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: After intensive searches on multiple occassions, I was unable to find anything decent which is open source. I have been using Obsidian on Pop!_OS for about 2 years now. For now it is okay for me. It is available on flathub as well on Obsidians's GitHub release page.

Answer (score 1):

## [Apostrophe](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/apostrophe)

| Distro | Available | Command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fedora 39 | Yes | `dnf install apostrophe` |
| Ubuntu 24.04 | Yes | `apt install apostrophe` |
| Pop!_OS 24.04 | Yes | `apt install apostrophe` |
| Debian 12 | Yes | `apt install apostrophe` |
| Kali Rolling | Yes | `apt install apostrophe` |

Answer (score 0):

(I started this as a comment to "izzy"'s answer but due to lack of formatting options I rewrote as an answer) - Thank you @izzy for mentioning this tool)

ReText works for me as follows:

1. On the commandline enter `retext --preview file.md`

OR (to make thins easier)

2. I did some changes in the Python sources of the installed package (**don't do this without copying the original files** - and know what you are doing ;-) )

*This is for version  7.0.1-1, running on Linux Mint 19.3 - things have changed a bit in newer versions*

- in `/usr/bin/retext` (Python) search for the line containing

  `previewMode = False` and change it to `previewMode = True`

This starts ReText in preview-mode only and you can start viewing with `retext file.md`

- in `/usr/share/retext/ReText/window.py` search for "view-refresh"
  and change **the line after** which is originally

  `lambda: self.currentTab.readTextFromFile())`

  to

  `lambda: self.currentTab.readTextFromFile(), shct=Qt.Key_F5)`

  to refresh using F5-key

Of course this whole "hack" is not "end user friendly", **not updateble** and you have to do this as "root" - but anyway, for me(!) it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

ghostwriter

has a nice interface

lookatme

has a good interface

mdp

picky with the terminal size, but quick and effective

formiko

gave me a SEG FAULT

*from:*

```
sudo apt search markdown
formiko/jammy,jammy 1.3.0-2 all — reStructuredText and MarkDown editor and live previewer
ghostwriter/jammy 2.1.1-1 amd64 — Distraction-free, themeable Markdown editor
lookatme/jammy,jammy 2.3.0-1 all — interactive command-line presentation tool
mdp/jammy 1.0.15-1 amd64 — command-line based Markdown presentation tool
```

Answer (score -1):

Markdown Viewer can be installed from Ubuntu Software.

The project site: 
https://github.com/mapitman/mdview

It is a command line tool that generates a temporary HTML file and open it in the browser.

Comment: See "not a browser addon, webapp or anything else that requires usage of browser" part of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft VSCode

At the command line, for instance, just enter "code " and, once opened, just Ctrl+Shift+V.

Comment: duplicate of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/53659/12551 answer