# Simple CommonsMark viewer for Ubuntu (standalone program, not something that requires usage of an internet browser)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, markdown, text

I am looking for a CommonMark viewer. It should:

- run locally on Ubuntu - be a normal program, not a browser addon, webapp or anything else that requires usage of an internet browser*

Preferable:

- simple and lightweight
- open source

Viewer as in "view formatted content". It is fine if viewer is also an editor.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331281/how-can-i-test-what-my-readme-md-file-will-look-like-before-committing-to-github for wider version of this question.

*I give an exception to browsers running in terminal in text mode

---

CommonsMark is either text format derived from Markdown or Markdown dialect, depending on how one may prefers to describe it.

It is used by GitHub, GitLab, Stack Exchange etc.

Note that it is not a duplicate of [Simple Markdown viewer for Ubuntu (standalone program, not something that requires usage of an internet browser)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17714/simple-markdown-viewer-for-ubuntu-standalone-program-not-something-that-requir) - the best program for viewing Markdown has no [CommonsMark support](https://github.com/retext-project/retext/issues/253)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that ghostwriter (obtainable via `apt-get install ghostwriter`) supports CommonMark in addition to Markdown.

Though note that its development [is stopped](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing).

[image]