# Markdown editor with structure view

Tags: linux, markdown

I'm doing a fairly large project in Markdown, and I'm looking for a good editor, either online or Linux-compatible.

The one feature that I'm looking for that I can't seem to find is some sort of structure view, similar to the [Structure View in Kile](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/extragear-office/kile/navigating.html). It doesn't have to be that complicated, though - basically, I'm looking for something that will let me easily navigate between large sections of a text without search or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

It also needs to have spell check and very preferably a word counter, but it doesn't need to have a preview function. Right now I'm using [Draft](https://draftin.com/), which is OK except for the lack of some sort of structure or table of contents view. (I'd also like something with better syntax highlighting and intelligent continuation of syntax, but that's not make-or-break for what I'm working on.)

Any suggestions? If not, I might get fed up enough to write my own.

Comment: For OSX, see: [Markdown editor for OSX that includes a preview, ideally in real time?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25/3474)

Comment: @Pterosaur I am building an editor, can you please explain *intelligent continuation*, its great to know user requirements, thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something with the functionality I'm looking for!

[StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) has a table of contents button on the upper right side that I'd missed before. (Lower right in StackEdit4). It brings up a menu that matches what you get from putting `[TOC]` in the Markdown. Clicking on any item in it brings both the editor and view panes to that location. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work with Firefox (at least not with 37.0.2 under Windows)

Comment: Very badly designed, though... It took me several minutes to find it! Now it is at the lower right side on a floating toolbar.

Comment: The new StackEdit 5 doesn't work with Firefox 58.0.2 either.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your document in Kile, (assuming that you are comfortable with it), save as latex and then use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert latex to markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/). It automatically generates a table of contents "hamburger menu" button at the lower right. This is actually stored in the resulting HTML, so it is usable not just while editing but also in the finished product (assuming you are targeting HTML).

The editor does have a spell-checker; the status bar shows line count and total character count, but not word count. It's free to use, with a paid version for more enterprise-oriented features.