# Markdown editor for *buntu with auto-ToC and drag-drop structure

Tags: linux, text-editor, ubuntu, markdown

I'm seeking a Markdown editor that is:

- ready-to-run on *buntu,
- and not an "online" editor;

and includes these two **features**:

1. auto-generated table of contents (ToC) from headings; and
2. the facility to drag-drop sections of the document to a new location internally.

The precise "feature set" I'm looking for here is available in [MultiMarkdown Composer, v. 2](http://multimarkdown.com/index.html) (scroll down to the "Table of Contents" heading):

[image: ToC panel]

But this fine editor is a Mac App. Here's what I have already seen/tried:

- [CuteMarkEd](http://cloose.github.io/CuteMarkEd/) which at least satisfies the first feature requirement (auto-ToC), but it looks like people have had trouble compiling it for Ubuntu, and compiling anything is outside my comfort zone.
- A related question (not a duplicate): "[Markdown editor with structure view](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10215/435)" on SoftwareRecs was satisfied by StackEdit's auto-ToC feature, but I don't want an app that runs in the browser.
- I have also tried a [Markdown ToC package](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-toc) for the Atom editor, but it struck me as cumbersome (and I had trouble invoking it anyway).

Of course it would be nice if there was a FOSS app that meets these criteria, but I would be interested to know of any editors that satisfy the spec.

Comment: Most editors can output HTML, maybe you could generate a TOC from that.

Comment: @JonasCz - thanks, but that kind of defeats the point of the exercise, which is to integrate document structure into the editor (and thus editing process) itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/)

After all these years, I've found that Obsidian meets my criteria. It has a [drag-and-drop re-structure](https://help.obsidian.md/Plugins/Outline) feature that works from an auto-generated Outline view (in a toggleable sidebar).

Obviously Obsidian does a lot more. It is not FOSS, though it does have a "free forever" personal version. Files are locally stored in simple Markdown which for me is ideal.

Also, it is cross-platform (versions available for Windows, MacOS, Linux of various flavours, and mobile versions for iOS and Android). My main workhorse platform is Ubuntu (and there is a `.deb` avaiable), with on-the-go being an ancient (2015) MacBook, so this is a real boon.

The first release (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsidian_(software))) was March 2020, so I've not been very swift to find it, but happy to have found it now.